# using .htaccess to rewrite .php file extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to use `.htaccess` to rewrite `example.php` to `example`.

The code I am using is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /example\.php\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule .+ http://www.example.com/example  [R=301,QSA]

RewriteRule ^example/? /example.php [QSA,L]
```

The page redirects but shows a 404 - page not found error.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I only want to rewrite this one page and not any other pages within the site

Many Thanks

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled with php?

Comment: You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Location /example>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Location>
```

and name your file "example" instead of "example.php"

See also the comments at:
http://support.modwest.com/content/5/1/en/can-i-have-all-html-pages-parsed-as-php.html?highlight=parse

Comment: While this is a solution, it can make it difficult to edit the file. You can no longer double-click to edit and yuo'll have to instruct your text editor to handle it as PHP every time.

Answer (score 1):

if you have only one page to rewrite do not use mod_rewrite, use a simple **Alias** instruction

```
Alias /example /my/dir/example.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this in apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```